# Java File Doesn't Load in Joomla Site

Tags: java, html, joomla

I am a total newbie in webdesign and I have created a site using the Joomla CMS. However, on a particular page within the site I am trying to launch an interactive calculator that uses java via .class files which are called by an .html file. I used the embedding tag:

```
<embed src="images/Calculator/classes/examples/PayeCalc.html" 
type="application/x-java-applet" 
width="1108" height="407">
```

Nothing shows up on the page however, when I preview it. What am I doing wrong? The .class files are saved in the folder that the .html file is located. Isn't it supposed to call up the files as needed? Why is the page just blank? Can anyone help this newbie to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you inserting this code into your website?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's going to filter out applets.  You might try to use a wrapper module.

Comment: Thank you guys for your quick response. I tried what you suggested in terms of the wrapper module, the JCE text editor and updating the filters. The JCE text editor was already the default editor as well as all the settings suggested in the article.

I tried the wrapper module option but what would I put as the url? I tried the location of the html file as the url but nothing showed up....

Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be? I am creating this site at my workplace and we use shared servers. Could it be that the servers do not allow java?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your text editor removes the embed tag.
It can happen from the joomla text filters or from the text editor.
Try using JCE text editor and follow the steps described [here](https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/faq/item/iframe-removed-on-saving)

Also if you use RSFirewall check [this](http://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/view-article/785-scrambled-tags-iframe-becomes-i-frame.html) out

Good luck

Comment: May also be good to mention that the tag might be in the **Prohibited Elements** filter option in the TinyMCE plugin, in the Plugins Manager

Comment: Thank you guys for your quick response. I tried what you suggested in terms of the wrapper module, the JCE text editor and updating the filters. The JCE text editor was already the default editor as well as all the settings suggested in the article.

I tried the wrapper module option but what would I put as the url? I tried the location of the html file as the url but nothing showed up....

Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be? I am creating this site at my workplace and we use shared servers. Could it be that the servers do not allow java?